# problema al momento de imprimir un arreglo bidimensional en C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Estoy haciendo un arreglo bidimensional de 50x8 y quiero que en la primera columna me guarde números consecutivos con ceros (0) a la izquierda, hasta ahorita ya logre esto y lo imprime bien, pero al momento de guardarlo en el arreglo e imprimirlo lo imprime así (imagen). Me transforma el numero guardado en código ASCII, ¿Saben por qué pasa esto?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<locale.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<Windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "spanish");

    char productos[50][8];
    int filas = 51, columnas = 9;




        cout << "\nProductos";

        for (int i = 0; i < filas; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < columnas; j++)
            {
                for (int k = 1; k < filas; k++)
                {
                    cout << "\nNumero de orden: ";
                    cout.fill('0');
                    cout.width(5);
                    cout << k;
                    cout << endl;
                    
                    productos[i][j] = k;
                    
                    cout << "Prueba: ";
                    cout.fill('0');
                    cout.width(5);
                    cout<<productos[i][j];
                    break;
                    
                }

                break;
            }
            break;
        }
        cout << "\n\n\nfin";
        

}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: `==` es una comparación. Asignar es `=`.

Comment: Pon un ejemplo que se entienda de cómo quieres que se muestre tu matriz por pantalla

Comment: @Trauma Mi error al copiar el código xd. Ya lo había hecho así pero sigue sin imprimirme el valor correcto, me imprime esto "0000☺", la carita es la que se pone con ALT+1, como si le dijera al programa que me convierta los valores ingresados en código ascii. Acabo de probar sumándole 48 a k para que convierta el numero guardado en los números que aparecen en el código ascii, pero como el código ascii solo tiene un máximo de 9 números (ALT+48 a ALT+57) solo imprime esos 9 números de manera correcta, a partir del numero 10 vuelve a ser símbolo :/

Comment: @Japv esa parte aun no la hago, esta solo es una impresión de prueba para ver si el arreglo imprime de manera correcta los valores ingresados pero sigue imprimiéndose mal : (

Comment: @AngelGonzalez, yo se que aún no la haces lo que quiero es que digas como se vería esa salida por pantalla

Comment: @Japv Oh ya, quiero hacer algo así (https://i.ytimg.com/vi/dJyPA0pFOgY/maxresdefault.jpg). Trato de hacer el menú de una tienda con SWITCH, en la primera opción se pedirán los datos para llenar la tabla(código, nombre de producto, precio, iva, etc.), en la segunda opción se mostraran los datos en forma de tabla. Ya he imprimido datos en forma de tablas en C++ así que esa parte es fácil, lo difícil es escribir el código porque suelo equivocarme y no encuentro el problema xd.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que lo más sencillo es que declares tu matriz como int

```
int productos[50][8];
```

Si es estrictamente necesario que sea char, puedes agregar un cero para indicar al compilador que deseas la expresión en número y no en ascii.

```
cout<<productos[i][j]+0;
```

Answer (score 0):

> Me transforma el numero guardado en código ASCII, ¿Saben por qué pasa esto?

Te imprime letras porque tu arreglo es de letras, así que el operador `<<` escoge la [sobrecarga de letras](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2):

```
template< class CharT, class Traits>
basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>& operator<<( basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>& os,
                                         CharT ch );
```

Si quieres que imprima números haz que tu arreglo sea de números (tal y como comenta [Victor Morales](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/428373/2742)) o escribe el código de manera que el compilador se vea forzado a usar una de las sobrecargas de números:

- Conversión implícita mediante [promoción aritmética](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion#Type_promotion) (idea de Victor Morales): al operar contra un entero (`int`) toda la expresión se transforma a entero (`int`).

  ```
  cout << productos[i][j] + 0;
  ```
- Conversión explícita:

  ```
  cout << static_cast<int>(productos[i][j]);
  ```